# Can my fingerings to start this piece be improved?

Tags: piano, fingering

I'm trying to complete the fingering for this entire piece, was wondering if my fingerings could be improved, so I don't finish the entire piece only to find out everything is wrong and stupidly done, I'm especially unsure about the chord fingerings because I know that chord fingerings could change depending on context to make chord transitions easier, in some context you play a major triad with 1 3 5 and in some context you play 1 2 4, depending on what's before and after it
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 1-2-3-5 in both arpeggios instead of 2-3-4-5. This way you have the correct intervals on your fingers as well (second-second-third). Personally I find the distance between the 4th and 5th finger using your fingering a bit awkward and difficult. Left hand looks fine.

I guess you started using 2 to avoid hitting a black key with your thumb, but I think its good practice to be able to use the thumb on a black key, especially when starting a phrase upwards.

Regardless, I think the best fingering is the one that you feel most comfortable with. If you can play this with your fingering with a relaxed wrist and fluently, that is fine. Eventually, with this particular example, you should be able to play it with both alternative fingerings to get some dexterity.

Comment: 'On the other hand' - which one..?

Comment: @Tim haha oh man that was the worst context for me to use that metaphorical phrase.. should change it for "Regardless/Anyhow/" or something alike

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand looks perfect! I recommend using 1,2,3,5 in the right hand as it fits better into your hand and will give you a better form.